# Mudblazor - Click inside the zone of the drag and drop

Tags: javascript, c#, css, blazor, mudblazor

I'm using a CSS framework for Blazor WebAssembly called Mudblazor.

I have added a button inside the drag and drop zone that will remove each image that has been uploaded. But when I click on the remove button, I only get the file manager up.

The problem is that the actual drag and drop zone is set to position: absolute none.

Is there a way to solve this?

Example of what this looks like. It is not possible to click on the remove button. File manager appears when I try to click the remove button.

[image]

CSS:

```
 .drag-drop-zone {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all .4s;
    /*        min-height: 400px;
*/ border: 3px dotted;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 2px dashed rgb(0, 135, 247);
}

.drag-drop-input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}

.drag-enter {
    box-shadow: var(--mud-elevation-10);
}

.list {
    padding: 2em;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Razor

```
<MudList Style="padding:2em;width:100%;" Dense="true">
@foreach (var file in fileNames)
{
    <MudListItem @key="@file">
        <MudChip Color="Color.Dark"
                 Style="width:60px; overflow:hidden;"
                 Text="@(file.Split(".").Last())" />
        @file <MudButton Color="Color.Error" OnClick="() => Remove(file)" Style="position:unset;">Remove</MudButton>
    </MudListItem>}
```

Remove method:

```
    void Remove(string file)
{
    var ret = fileNames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(file));
    if (ret != null)
    {
        fileNames.Remove(ret);
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention the link for Mudblazor: https://mudblazor.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when using the sample code from MudBlazor home page
https://mudblazor.com/components/fileupload#drag-and-drop-example

As Memetican states it seemed like the `.drag-drop-input` was overlaying the other content. I dont know what I am doing, so I will not give an explanation but the `position: absolute;` part caught my interest. Reading about it  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) led me to changing it from `absolute` to `static`. Together with some other minor changes from the sample code I have the following that seems to be working

```
@page "/tools/csvimport"
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar
<style>
    .drag-drop-zone {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        transition: all .4s;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .drag-drop-input {
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .drag-enter {
        box-shadow: var(--mud-elevation-10);
    }

    .list {
        padding: 2em;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<MudGrid Justify="Justify.Center" Spacing="4">

    <MudItem xs="12" sm="12" md="6">
        <MudPaper @ondragenter="@(()=>_dragEnterStyle="drag-enter")"
                  @ondragleave="@(()=>_dragEnterStyle=null)"
                  @ondragend="@(()=>_dragEnterStyle=null)"
                  Class=@("drag-drop-zone "+ _dragEnterStyle)
                  MinHeight="200px">

            <InputFile OnChange="OnInputFileChanged" class="drag-drop-input" />

            @if (file is null)
            {
                <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Drag file here, or click to browse your files</MudText>
            }
            else
            {
                <MudChip Color="Color.Info">@file.Name</MudChip>
            }


        </MudPaper>
        <MudGrid Justify="Justify.Center" Spacing="4" Class="mt-4">
            <MudItem>
                <MudButton OnClick="Upload" Disabled="@(file is null)" Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Filled">Upload</MudButton>
            </MudItem>
            <MudItem>
                <MudButton OnClick="@(() => file = null)" Disabled="@(file is null)" Color="Color.Error" Variant="Variant.Filled">Clear</MudButton>
            </MudItem>
        </MudGrid>
    </MudItem>

</MudGrid>
@code {
    string _dragEnterStyle;
    IBrowserFile file;

    void OnInputFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        file = e.File;
    }
    void Upload()
    {
        //Upload the files here
        Snackbar.Configuration.PositionClass = Defaults.Classes.Position.TopCenter;
        Snackbar.Add("TODO: Upload " + file.Name, Severity.Normal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've left out the code for your drop target, as most of your CSS styles aren't referenced.

However, it appears that your drop target is positioned *on top of* your files list. Note the `z-index` in your CSS...

```
.drag-drop-input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2; /* <== here */
}
```

This would create a glass-pane type effect. You can see your files list and remove buttons, because you have `opacity: 0;` - however you can't interact with them because your drop target is above them in the z-order.

Think of an HTML page as a bunch of overlapping rectangles. Mouse interactions hit the topmost layer only.

**Solution 1: (workable)** Remove that z-index, or set the z-index for your files list and your buttons higher than the drop target. This should work however it may create undesirable behaviors on some browsers, if the user tries to drop a file directly on your file list, or your remove buttons.

**Solution 2: (recommended)** Move your file list and *remove* buttons outside of the drop target. Design your drop target do its one function- accepting file drops, and mouse clicks that invoke the file upload action.